# passing parameter to a trig function to draw nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{45} % angle
\pgfmathsetmacro{\da}{45} % delta angle
\node [] at ( cos{\a+\da}, sin{\a+\da}) {2: \a+\da};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

When passing 2 parameters to cos, I get a different value.
for example,
if a=90 and da=0 I get a node
and if a=45 and da=45 I get a different node...

I expect both nodes be the same since cos(\a+\da) should produce the same result.

What am I missing?

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome on TeX.SE.

Your question is not very clear, but You make confusion between  ( ) and braces { }.

1. The PGF math functions use parentheses, hence you should use, e.g. `cos(\a+\da)`
2. When `x` or `y` coordinate contains parentheses, You should "hide" them with braces, e.g. write:

`( {cos(\a+\da)}, {sin(\a+\da)} )`

3. For the latter, you could more simply use polar coordinates: `(\a+\da :1)`